# Jenkins redirect / to /jenkins on standalone installation

Tags: jenkins

We have the standard Debian installation of Jenkins (winstone only, no tomcat or apache involved), which we are running with `--prefix=/jenkins` and on port 80.

Now when I access `http://my.server/` I get a 404 page. Can I convince Winstone somehow to redirect that to the correct address `http://my.server/jenkins/`?

EDIT: I know I could install Apache, and use the following Rewrite Rule to get what I want:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/*$ https://jenkins.corp.mobile.de/jenkins/ [R]
```

My question is how to do this in Winstone.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to do what you want is to run Jenkins in some high port, like 8080 with `--prefix=/jenkins` and then run something like Apache or Nginx in port 80 configured to reverse proxy `/jenkins` to `http://localhost:8080/jenkins`

For Apache, you could add something like this to Apache's config file:

```
ProxyPass         /jenkins  http://localhost:8080/jenkins
ProxyPassReverse  /jenkins  http://localhost:8080/jenkins
ProxyRequests     Off

# Allow direct access to Jenkins only from localhost i.e. Apache
<Proxy http://localhost:8080/jenkins*>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Proxy>
```

You should tune the access controls in the  directive according to where you want to accept connections to Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't really what I asked :-)

Answer (score 0):

The trick which worked for me was described [here](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Running-Hudson-as-another-user-td369946.html). Shortly, execute the following commands:

```
sudo service jenkins stop
sudo rm -rf /tmp/*
sudo service jenkins start
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see what that has to do with my question? The link you posted describes a problem with different user accounts.

Answer (score -2):

The proper way to do that is to go on your DNS provider and change the redirection for

http://my.server/

at present it should point to your home directory, called /
you should chnage it to /jenkins

I personnaly like to define subdomains for webapps such as http://jenkins.my.server/ and keep www.myserver for other purpose.

This can be also achieve within your DNS provider configuration